# Tkinter Label is missing - Python not working correctly?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm trying to get started with `Tkinter`.

I wrote my first little piece of code. A window opens and a button appears, but the label is missing.

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    label.config(text="Button was clicked!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('400x300')
root.pack_propagate(False)

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me!", command=button_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
type here
```

The window is black with a white button.
When i just use the label without a button the window turns white and is completly empty.

Just tried the code on different device and there it works.
Im not sure, but I think something with my python settings is wrong, maybe I installed it wrongly. Im working in PyCharm

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.16. Is your platform MacOS?

Comment: Yes it is. On other MacOS Devices I works

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Python downloaded from python.org?

Comment: I have uninstalled pyCharm and installed it again. I've just dowloaded the newest version of python via python.org. How can I implent it into pyCharm?

Comment: Did you read PyCharm [document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Op using MacOS.

If you are using MacOS. Then remove prefix `tk.`

```
from tkmacosx import Label, Button
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    label.config(text="Button was clicked!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('400x300')
root.pack_propagate(False)

label = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack()

button = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=button_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```